# Vertical Seekbar Not Functioning

Tags: java, android, android-studio, seekbar, android-studio-2.1

XML Code

[image]

Design View

[image]

Me and my friend tried making a vertical seekbar, however it does not seem to be functioning properly. This is our first time using Android Studio, is there anything else we should be adding to the code?

Answer (score 0):

try use android:rotation="-90" to the seekbar

```
       <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seek"
        android:layout_width="261dp"
        android:layout_height="26dp"
        android:progress="0"
        android:rotation="-90"
        />
```